# R: calculate percentages for correct/incorrect button presses

Tags: r, count, response, aggregate, percentage

I have data that where participants saw faces and had to press one of 7 buttons (every button corresponding to an emotion) that leaves me with this kind of data:

```
    X...Emotion Intensity Response   Correct Button.RB
1       Anger       40%      Sad Incorrect         5
2         Sad      100%      Sad   Correct         5
3       Happy       50%    Happy   Correct         4
4       Anger      100%    Anger   Correct         1
5        Fear      100%     Fear   Correct         3
```

Now, I want to calculate the percentage correct button presses for every emotion and the total percentage incorrect, but also the kind of mistakes someone made (e.g. for an 'angry face' there are 35% incorrect responses, of which 7,5% were 'sad' button presses, 22,5% was 'neutral' button presses etc...)

I figured out how to get the individual counts for every emotion and correct/incorrect:

```
count(df_fert, vars = c('X...Emotion','Correct'))
```

Which provides me with:

```
X...Emotion   Correct freq
1        Anger   Correct   26
2        Anger Incorrect   14
3      Disgust   Correct   11
4      Disgust Incorrect   29
```

Does somebody know a way to calculate percentages the way I want to? And also how to 'subdivide' the incorrect responses in the type of response?

Answer (score 1):

It's good to see that you solved it by yourself. I gave this a try and here is how I did it:

**Data setup**

```
# Setup
set.seed(1110)
Emot = c("Sad", "Happy", "Angry", "Fear", "Joy", "Neutral")
Emotion = sample(x = Emot, size = 50, replace = T)
Response = sample(x = Emot, size = 50, replace = T)
df = data.frame(Emotion,Response)
df$Correct = ifelse(Emotion==Response, "Correct", "Incorrect")
```

This gives:

```
> head(df,10)
   Emotion Response   Correct
1    Angry      Joy Incorrect
2      Joy  Neutral Incorrect
3  Neutral  Neutral   Correct
4     Fear    Happy Incorrect
5    Happy  Neutral Incorrect
6      Sad    Happy Incorrect
7    Angry    Angry   Correct
8  Neutral      Sad Incorrect
9     Fear     Fear   Correct
10   Angry    Happy Incorrect
```

**Counting**

To count the answers by pair combinations of Emotion and Response do:

```
# Counting by Emotion and Response
df2 = aggregate(data = df, Correct ~ Emotion + Response, FUN = length)
```

This gives:

```
> head(df2,10)
   Emotion Response Correct
1    Angry    Angry       1
2    Happy    Angry       1
3      Joy    Angry       1
4  Neutral    Angry       1
5      Sad    Angry       4
6    Angry     Fear       1
7     Fear     Fear       1
8    Happy     Fear       1
9      Joy     Fear       2
10 Neutral     Fear       2
```

**Percentages**

To calculate the correct and incorrect percentages for all emotions and for each type of response do:

```
library(reshape2)
results = dcast(df2, Emotion ~ Response, value.var = "Correct")
results[is.na(results)] = 0
results[,-1] = round( results[,-1]/rowSums(results[,-1])*100, digits = 2)
```

This gives:

```
> results
  Emotion Angry  Fear Happy   Joy Neutral   Sad
1   Angry  9.09  9.09 18.18 27.27   27.27  9.09
2    Fear  0.00 16.67 33.33 16.67   16.67 16.67
3   Happy 20.00 20.00  0.00 40.00   20.00  0.00
4     Joy 12.50 25.00 12.50 12.50   12.50 25.00
5 Neutral  9.09 18.18 27.27  0.00   18.18 27.27
6     Sad 44.44  0.00 11.11 22.22   22.22  0.00
```

For example: The Angry emotion was correctly clicked 9.09% and it was clicked incorrectly as Happy 18.18%.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with this code:

```
freq <- count(df_fert, vars = c('X...Emotion','Response','Correct'))
freq$perc <- (freq$freq/40)*100
```